# $request->file returns null when performing a PUT request

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm working on a Vue.js/Laravel web application for a company that offers school workshops. I've managed to make it possible to add an image to a workshop when it doesn't yet have one (POST), but when I try to update an existing workshop picture (PUT), $request->file always returns null and I can't seem to figure out why.

Workshops table:

[image]

Uploads table:

[image]

(workshop_picture contains the id of the corresponding upload in the uploads table)
onFileSelected function in the workshop edit page:

```
      onFileSelected (event) {
        this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]

        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file', event.target.files[0])

        if (this.workshop.workshop_picture) {
          console.log('Workshop already has a picture, updating current picture...')
          axios.put('/api/upload/' + this.workshop.workshop_picture.id,
            formData,
            { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
            .then(response => {
              this.workshop.workshop_picture = response.data.id
              this.workshop_picture_preview = '/uploads/' + response.data.internal_name
            })
            .catch(function () {
              alert('Uploaden mislukt!')
            })
        }
      }
```

UploadController.php:

```
class UploadController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate(['file' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg']);

        $internal_name = Str::random(32) . '.' . $request->file->extension();

        $upload = new Upload();
        $upload->name = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $upload->internal_name = $internal_name;
        $upload->size = $request->file->getSize();
        $upload->save();

        $request->file->move(public_path('uploads'), $internal_name);

        return response($upload, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'json');
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate(['file' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg']);

        $internal_name = Str::random(32) . '.' . $request->file->extension();

        $upload = Upload::find($id);
        $upload->name = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $upload->internal_name = $internal_name;
        $upload->size = $request->file->getSize();
        $upload->save();
        $request->file->move(public_path('uploads'), $internal_name);

        return response($upload, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'json');

    }

}
```

[image]

The form data clearly contains the selected file, so I have absolutely no clue why it says $request->file is null.

[image]

Comment: Since it passes validation I'm going to assume the file is actually there (though make it required just in case). Somewhere so try using `$requst->file('file')->extension()` in case `->file` looks at the wrong place

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sadly, looking for 'file' specifically doesn't make a difference.